# Toolbar in an iphone app

Tags: iphone, user-experience

I'm currently developing an iphone app where I have one screen that includes a web view. I was wondering where to place the toolbar (back, forward, and refresh buttons) knowing that I have to keep the navigation bar for consistency reasons and there is the tab bar which is always showing in my app. I don't want to place the toolbar just under the navigation bar in order not to loose space for the content of the web page. 
Can I include my toolbar controls (back, forward, and refresh buttons) in the navigation bar or by that I will by violating the iOS guidelines ? What is the best user experience here ?

Thanks in advance.
Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your toolbar at the bottom of the screen. It wouldn't be a good user experience to have browser controls on the nav bar because it's easy to confuse nav bar "back" with browser "back", and generally there isn't enough rooom.

You'd be in good company if you did this - it's what the Facebook iPhone app does (and many others).

Note: the iPad Facebook app does put some browser controls on the RHS of the nav bar, because there's enough room.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a toolbar, but set `controller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES` on the web view controller, so that your tab bar is not visible while in the web view.

You should probably also use https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController and save yourself a lot of time ;)

Comment: But, I need the tab bar to be visible all the time.